# How to get only those colums in a EXCEL worksheet that have a value

Tags: c#, excel, excel-2007

I am programatically reading an Excel file in C#.

When I use Excel.Worksheet.Columns.columns.count, I get a value above 16,000.

But my excel sheet has only 15 columns. How do I get **only those columns that have a value**?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Here is how I usually do this:

```
Excel.Application demoApp= new Excel.Application();
demoApp.Workbooks.Open(fileName);
int rowCount = demoApp.ActiveSheet.UsedRange.Rows.Count;
int colCount = demoApp.ActiveSheet.UsedRange.Columns.Count;
```

so, the key is to use **UsedRange**, I hope this will help.

Answer (score 0):

When trying to automate Excel, you can first figure out how to do what you want in Excel, then figure out the way to make that happen using the automation API.

Imagine you are using the "real" Excel and you position the active cell at the very end of the row that contains the columns you are trying to narrow down to.  Lets say "XFD1" for that last column of the first row.  This is where the 16,000+ number comes from.

To get to the last cell that contains a non-empty value, you can press the `End` key to enter "End Mode" and then press `Left Arrow` and this will position the active cell, for your spreadsheet, in column 15, or column "O" with address "O1".

What is the equivalent C# automation API for "End Mode"?  It is the `Range.End` function.  Here is a description:

- [Range.End Property](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.office.interop.excel.range.end%28v=office.14%29.aspx)

and here are some VBA examples of the `End` function:

- [Excel Ranges: Finding the Last Cell in a Range](http://www.ozgrid.com/VBA/ExcelRanges.htm)

Excel hasn't changed much over the years so these VBA examples are very prevalent and still quite useful, even if you have to translate the syntax to C#.

If you can do it in Excel itself, you can probably do it using the automation API!