# How Do I Stop Access From Importing Every Excel Cell

Tags: excel, ms-access, import

In Access and Excel 2013, I am simply trying to import an Excel tab into Access. For some reason, Access is importing all 1,048,575 rows, but only the 42 columns I have in the Excel sheet. I am positive (through several methods and attempts) that there are no blank cells or random data entered into an obscure cell - its clean. Does anyone know why Access is bringing every row in? I have let Access dictate the primary key, created my own, added a column, etc - still brings in every row.

I appreciate the help.

Comment: Sometimes Excel gets confused and enlarges its "used range" all the way to the end. If you do "Ctrl+End" on the Excel sheet, what's the row number the selected cell gets to?

Comment: If possible import a worksheet instead of the Cells collection of a worksheet. My experience is operating with Worksheets is optimized over Ranges and Cells for large data.

Comment: here is a question that talks about UsedRange They said if you save the file then Excel refreshes the buffer. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6172301/how-to-get-only-those-colums-in-a-excel-worksheet-that-have-a-value

Comment: Using CTRL+End does send the active cell to the very last cell - XFD1048576. Thanks for the ideas - I believe on import I'm referring to a worksheet tab rather than a range. I'll check the other thread out too. Thanks.

Comment: how many rows of data do you have in Excel?  what data is in the Access table that correspond to blank Excel rows?  0's, empty strings, nulls?

Comment: I'm setting up the base for a new table in this DB so there are only about 600 rows right now. But allowing Access to add a PK to the set adds all 1M plus rows. Even adding a new column in the source 'AccessID' to dictate my own PK on import gives me the Cannot Have Null or Empty ID values error, even though there's nothing in those cells.

Comment: The trick I use when the Excel Used Range gets screwed up like that is to select all rows that are not needed and do "right-click->Delete" in the row header column to completely delete those empty rows. To select all such rows quickly, select the first row past your data and type Ctrl+Shift+Down Arrow. Then save your workbook and exit. When you restart Excel and load your workbook, the Used Range is back to normal. It should stay ok for a while but, if it happens again, do the same trick and you're fine.

Comment: I'm actually doing that right now - deleting the empty cells and shifting up has configured the Used Range to AT529, which appears to be random still, but progress. This is another user's sheet so I guess this could be expected. Thanks for the help.

Comment: You're welcome. This thing sometimes happens when the user selects a whole column by clicking its header and adds some formatting. I've not really been able to narrow it down exactly, but it appears it's something to do with full-column formatting of sorts. The trick of deleting the superfluous rows, save, exit and restart works every time.

Answer (score 0):

Deleting (right click delete) all cells below the data, within the populated rows, configures the Used Range to the cells that contain data, rather than the final cell in the worksheet in Excel.